# adding element to an existing struct makes function crash on segmentation error

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have the following struct:

```
struct FeatureMatch {
    int id1, id2;
    double score; 
};
```

which runs fine when called by this function:

```
void ssdMatchFeatures(const FeatureSet &f1, const FeatureSet &f2, vector<FeatureMatch> &matches, double &totalScore) {
    int m = f1.size();
    int n = f2.size();
    matches.resize(15000);
    totalScore = 0;

    double d;
    double dBest;
    int idBest;
   printf("2");
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++) {
        dBest = 1e100;
        idBest = 0;

        for (int j=0; j<n; j++) {
            d = distanceSSD(f1[i].data, f2[j].data);

            if (d < dBest) {
        dBest = d;
        idBest = f2[j].id;
            }
        }
        printf("1\n");
        matches[i].id1 = f1[i].id;
        matches[i].id2 = idBest;
        matches[i].score = -dBest;
     //   matches[i].second=1;
        totalScore += matches[i].score;
    }

    printf("3");
}
```

However, as soon as I modify the struct by adding a new element:

```
struct FeatureMatch {
    int id1, id2;
    double score, second; 
};
```

An additional double value called second makes the above function crash on segmentation error. The output of 1,2,3 shows something like:

21
1
1
1
1
.
.
.
1

But never gets to 3 before it crashes.

what is going on here? Even if I never modify matches[i].second, this happens.

Comment: Do you have multiple source files? Rebuild *everything*, to make sure you don't have a module using a stale definition somewhere. (If that fixes it, consider adding or fixing dependency support in your Make process.)

Comment: Also, though this might sound obvious, make sure `m < 15000`, or (better) use `matches.resize(m)`.

Comment: @nneonneo yea m is less than 15000, it is matches.resize(m) in my code, but i replaced it here just for clarity.

Comment: If this isn't a build problem, then most likely the program has a problem even without the extra member, and the extra member is just making the problem more obvious by making it crash.  If you can, use valgrind to help see what the real problem is.

Comment: @nneonneo how do i do a rebuild of everything in eclipse?

Comment: dunno if he will, but i'll certainly up vote ya, nneonneo. good call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change a structure definition, you should rebuild all affected source files if your build tool doesn't automatically do so. Otherwise, you may link together modules that use different definitions for the structure, which will result in confusing bugs (as you have seen).